# How to remove part of the string starting from special char (or word) in ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml

so I have a string "bla dla dla vre bla 54312" I want to turn it into "bla dla dla " by saying something like 
function(string, "vre");
how to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you know how to write the function around this, but this is all you really need to do what you're asking. Check out the liveDocs for details about the subString and indexOf methods.

```
var newString:String;

newString = "bla dla dla vre bla 54312"

newString = newString.subString(0,newString.indexOf("vre"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started:

```
var s:String = "bla dla dla vre bla 54312";
var a:Array  = s.split("vre");

if(a) {
    // a[0] should be 'bla dla dla'
    trace(a[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with actionscript syntax, but this seems like it'd be fairly easy. You could try:

```
function trimStr(myStr, searchStr)
{    
    var index:Int = myStr.search(searchStr);

    if (index > -1)
    {
        return myStr.substring(0, index);
    }
    else
    {
        return myStr;
    }
}
```

I may've gotten some syntax wrong, but the basic concept still comes through.

Comment: Yknow, I had it as int initially but in an example I saw String, so I assumed they were consistent :p